# Spring boot + (Thymeleaf is overriding React JS views)

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created an error page with Thymeleaf and I use it that way because I can send error messages to users through the controller.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView controllerExceptionHandler(
    Exception e,
    HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    String[] messages = e.getMessage().split("</br>");
    mav.addObject("message", messages);
    mav.addObject("timestamp", new Date());
    mav.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());

    mav.addObject("headerMessage", "Error :(");
    mav.addObject("contentMessage", "We are working hard to resolve it.");
    mav.setViewName("error");

    mav.addObject("status", 500);

    return mav;
}
```

In template file I have something like this:

```
<h1 class="mr-3 pr-3 align-top border-right inline-block align-content-center" th:text="${status}">404</h1>
<div class="inline-block align-middle">
    <div>
        <h1>Something went wrong...</h1>
    </div>
    <th:block th:each="msg : ${message}">
        <h2 class="font-weight-normal lead" id="desc" th:text="${msg}">The page you requested was not found.</h2>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

Previously I had a simple React JS application also running with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and then I used Thymeleaf template to show that. I had a template index.html where was actually React JS build file, so every time I had to copy the build file inside there, JS and CSS files into a static folder (after build). Now the React APP got more complex and I decided to use frontendmaven plugin to build it straight away with backend.

How to tell Spring Boot to not try to use Thymeleaf when resolving ReactJS views? This is how I serve ReactJS views.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Or would it be possible to get rid of Thymeleaf? Is it possible to send variables to ReactJS views through Java controllers when serving those views? The modelandview example?

Answer (score 2):

> How to tell Spring Boot to not try to use Thymeleaf when resolving
>   React JS views?

Remove ThymeleafViewResolver in webconfiguration and switch to Rest api ( @Restcontroller instead of @Controller ). This way you are telling Spring for not to render a view instead act as api-endpoints.

Now you can update your react code to call these Spring rest apis, prebuilt using maven-frontend-plugin and deploy.

> Now the question comes, what is the stating point for your application

Only for this purpose, you can create a single controller which will handle request to "/" and will return index page residing under resources/template folder. This index.html page will be using your prebuilt react pages as -

```
<script src="built/bundle.js"></script>
```

Demo application: https://github.com/ankidaemon/Spring5-ReactJS/tree/master/Section5/Video5.3/SpringSecurity-Reactjs-RestAPI

> Is it possible to send variables to React JS views through Java
>   controllers when serving those views

This is called server-side-rendering, however for react this is different then jsp and freemarker, thymeleaf etc and I would say not an easy way to do it with react. You can try your luck with this -> https://codeburst.io/jsx-react-js-java-server-side-rendering-ssr-2018-cf3aaff7969d

Comment: 1. If changing it to @RestController it now returns just a String and not a view. 2. So I could get rid of the "return 'index.html'" part with this solution right by using this bundle .js?

Comment: Not just the Restcontroller. You need to create a Controller as well to return index.html page to start rendering react pages. Check my demo example for all details

Comment: And for bundle.js file i need webback? Not only yarn will do it.

Comment: Yarn is just a package manager. You need babel and webpack . Babel is a compiler and webpack is the bundler. Also you might want to change the question header since this is more of "reactjs with spring boot' question

Comment: So in the package.json I should also tell to use webpack? Currently it's "react-scripts buld" that the Maven Frontend is calling

Comment: Maven frontend plugin will run webpack build also. Again take a look at demo application for configuration